# Json / gson (de)serializing nested objects

Tags: json, nested, deserialization, gson

Any idea on how it would be possible to handle this kind of json structures with gson?, or other lib if more adapted

```
[{
    "name": "john",
    "link": []
}, {
    "name": "mike",
    "link": [{
        "name": "kate",
        "link": []
    }, {
        "name": "john",
        "link": []
    }]
}, {
    "name": "jane",
    "link": [{
        "name": "tyler",
        "link": [{
            "name": "evan",
            "link": []
        }]
    }]
}]
```

a list of objects (name, link), link the same kind of list of these objects
so there's variable depth

Comment: nothing, since with gson I don't know much things, only deserializing into a list of objects, not helpful there

Comment: Going to try to deser.. in a Class Foo{string name; arraylist<Foo> link; ...with hope

Comment: that's a great idea, i think it will work!

Answer (score 1):

The JSON structure is a natural fit for a multidimensional array, or a multidimensional list of lists.  Deserializing it as such with Gson is relatively simple.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    // Deserialized as a multidimensional array:
    BarsArray[] barsArray = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), BarsArray[].class);
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(barsArray));

    // Deserialized as a multidimensional list of lists:
    List<BarsList> barsList = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("input.json"), new TypeToken<List<BarsList>>(){}.getType());
    System.out.println(gson.toJson(barsList));
  }
}

class BarsArray
{
  String name;
  BarsArray[] link;
}

class BarsList
{
  String name;
  List<BarsList> link;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmh. What's wrong with the obvious Object definition:

```
public class Node {
    public String name;
    public Node[] link; // or List<Node>
}
```

and then binding `Node[]` or `List<Node>` using GSON, or other data-binding library (like Jackson).

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your json manually using the GSON raw collections api. This should be straightforward as your structure is quite regular. See [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/extras/examples/rawcollections/RawCollectionsExample.java) for an example: